# How to update two columns of one table in which second column will be updated with the value of first column?

Tags: mysql, sql

If I have two columns phone id,phone and address in table phone in which phone id is id-column. Now I have requirement to update phone column with current time(taking 4 digits of current time ) + adding the existing phone value ; If phone column changes then address value also changes since 4 digits of address is phone. how to do this ??

```
Phoneid  Phone  Address
1        123    123newdelhi10091
```

After update

```
Phoneid  Phone              Address
1        (123+4467)4590    4590newdelhi110091
```

Comment: What is your _expected_ result? What have you tried? What hasn't worked?

Comment: it's not a smart idea to add a 4 digit time to an phone number, is it?

Answer (score 0):

Often, this type of behavior would be considered business logic, so it would be done in whatever program is connected to the DB. If that is not an option, there are a couple of ways to address.

First, you could create a trigger, which basically will automatically change one value when the other changes:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER phone_update BEFORE UPDATE ON phone
FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN
       SET NEW.Address = CONCAT(NEW.Phone, SUBSTRING(OLD.Address, LENGTH(Old.Phone);
   END;//
```

Triggers are often counter-intuitive and hard to debug. In addition, future developers may not expect triggers. I'm generally not a fan if I can help it.

Your other would be to use a view:

```
CREATE VIEW phone_address_view AS (
    SELECT phoneid, phone, CONCAT(phone, address) as `address` FROM phone
);
```

The benefit of a view is that you will always have consistent data. You would insert an actual address into the DB and then you would receive the modified information back when you query.

On the other hand, you're now SELECTing from a different place than you're INSERTing and UPDATEing. Views also have a reputation of being slower than a raw table.